# ExtJS-3.4 Resize component(textfield/textarea) based on contents

Tags: extjs, extjs3, extjs-form

I like to add **textfields** in my **formpanel** where the contents to fields will be added dynamically ,so I want the fields to resize automatically in both (width and height). I have tried the "grow:true" property in **"textfield"** but only the width get increased. Any suggestions to resize on both width as well as **height**.

```
    items = [
        {
           xtype: 'textfield',
           fieldLabel: 'DataValue',
           name: 'dataValue',
           grow: true,
           growMax: 500
       }]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not so sure you can achieve this with the textfield component, using a textarea will allow multiple lines of text to be entered, and will work with grow:true configured. But on initial display, the textarea is displayed with a fixed height, which may not be what you want.

Comment: @mindparse  thanks for the reply. i will go with the textarea.

Comment: @mindparse Meanwhile when I go with **textarea** I have provided the **growMin: 20** option for the initial height control . the initial height works fine. But when I enter single character in it , height of the textarea increases (about 1 row )automatically. I want the height to be increased only the content reaches EOL.